# C# HtmlNode parsing throws Collection was modified error

Tags: list, http, parsing, collections, html-agility-pack

This looks a bit weird to me. I have an `HtmlDocument` and while parsing I'm getting:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'

What is weird to me is that I am not looping through the List returned from my code and I still receive this error.

```
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
             using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
             {
                  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw if httpcode is an error
                  using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                       {
                             string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                             var website = new HtmlDocument();
                             website.LoadHtml(result);
                             //Thread.Sleep(5000);
                             List<HtmlNode>topbar = website.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "valueofClass")
                                 .Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "valueofClass").Elements("section").ToList();
                             //loop
                       }
            }
      }
```

If I add a `Sleep` code seems to work without any issues which makes me think that `LoadHtml` is still working in the background or I am executing some kind of `javascript`, which I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following to get a `HtmlNodeCollection` by using `SelectNodes` instead of running `Descendants` twice after a query to get a single node.

```
    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var website = new HtmlDocument();
                website.LoadHtml(result);

                HtmlNodeCollection topbar = website.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='valueofClass']//section");

                if (topbar != null)
                    foreach (HtmlNode node in topbar) 
                    {
                        ....
                    }
            }
```

**topbar** contains a list of all possible nodes that are `div` with class name `valueofClass` containing tag `section`, which is what I assume you are trying to get with Descendants and FirstOrDefault lookups.

Other thing I see is that in your `FirstOrDefault` statements, you are using `==` comparison for strings. I would recommend using `.Equals()` to correctly compare the two strings, if you want to go with Descendants route. If your comparison is giving a null in the first `FirstOrDefault` statement, then second `Descendants` is going to fail with `Object reference not set to instance of an object.`

**Update:**

If you want to use the statement you have with multiple descendants, I would recommend using `ToList()` to convert the `IEnumerable` result of Descendants and then filtering it with FirstOrDefault(). This will help with the error you are getting.

```
  website.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("div").ToList()
        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "valueofClass")
    .Descendants("div").ToList()
        .FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "valueofClass")
    .Elements("section").ToList();
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this is just a different writing of parsing.
I will give it a shot later as I am away now and see what it gives.